# IIS logging best practice in regards to Read Only setting

Tags: asp.net, iis, logging, asp.net-web-api, nlog

If I have an asp.net webAPI where I am doing my own custom logging is there a best practice in regards of where to put these logs?

Initially I was trying to log to ${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}.log. However my basedir was the old name of my project and I didn't know where this value was coming from or how to change it?

However the next thing i noticed is that the logs folder seems to be read only where IIS default logs to. And I cant seem to change this. I am thinking when IIS runs it by default makes this read only so no one can delete the logs during a malicious attack.

So instead I decided to log to a different directory to avoid this problem. Is this the best practice or should try a different approach I am using Nlog if its relevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I'd call it best practice but in my experience logging locally to files doesn't scale very well to a production environment:

- If you are load balanced across multiple web servers then you have to try and pull together log files from multiple sources and correlate events
- you have to log in to production boxes to try and retrieve your logs in the first place meaning no one without full production access can diagnose issues from the logs.

Alternatives include logging to a central database or (my preferred option now) logging to a log server such as [seq](http://getseq.net). You can log to seq using NLog by following their [NLog documentation page](https://getseq.atlassian.net/wiki/display/SEQ10/Writing+events+from+NLog)

If you do want to use files on disc then I'd suggest a set of rolling log files in a "logs" sub folder of the application root.

Comment: +1 thanks. I think I am fine scaling wise because when the machines are rolled out in the cloud we automatically have a splunk forwarder on them consolidating the logs. 

will look into Seq that seems like a good/better idea.